# Wordpress SQL query consuming 100% CPU

Tags: mysql, wordpress

This is my Wordpress SQL query:

```
    SELECT id
    FROM   wp_posts AS posts
           LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS postmeta
                  ON postmeta.post_id = posts.id
           LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
                  ON mt1.post_id = posts.id
           LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2
                  ON mt2.post_id = posts.id
    WHERE  posts.post_type = 'job'
           AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
       AND ( postmeta.meta_key = 'jobsearch_field_job_publish_date'
             AND postmeta.meta_value <= 1601168682 )
       AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'jobsearch_field_job_expiry_date'
             AND mt1.meta_value >= 1601168682 )
       AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'jobsearch_field_job_status'
             AND mt2.meta_value = 'approved' )
ORDER  BY id DESC
```

This query is consuming 100% on my Ubuntu server of 2GB and I am not able to understand why. Please suggest on how this can be fixed.

EXPLAIN plan of the SQL:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type   | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref                    | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mt2      | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | meta_key | 767     | const                  | 2484 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type_status_date | PRIMARY  | 8       | ccbmbdeaba.mt2.post_id |    1 |    14.48 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | postmeta | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | ccbmbdeaba.mt2.post_id |   46 |     0.11 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mt1      | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | ccbmbdeaba.mt2.post_id |   46 |     0.11 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: provide `EXPLAIN` of the query

Comment: if you are using the column of the LEFT JOIN table in where clause then what is the purpose of left join you could have just joined the table instead of left join

Comment: added EXPLAIN plan.

Comment: you have not added any index in where clause columns, do share `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of the table to understand the structure of the table